# image.sampleRegions is not a function (supervised classification at google earth engine)

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

Hello I'm a beginner currently working on supervised classification in Google Earth Engine. I can't seem to get past the problem 'image.sampleRegions is not a function'. Here are the script that I use.

```js
/**
 * Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 * @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
 */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                  .filterDate('2019-09-01', '2019-10-01') //september
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',20))
                  .map(maskS2clouds);

var visualization = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

Map.setCenter(101.68287285738528,0.6988384299139916, 16);
Map.addLayer(dataset.mean(), visualization, 'RGB');

// Use these bands for prediction.
var bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B10', 'B11'];


// Make a FeatureCollection from the hand-made geometries.
var polygons = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(Kebun1, {'class': 0}),
  ee.Feature(Kebun2, {'class': 0}),
  ee.Feature(Kebun3, {'class': 0}),
  ee.Feature(Canal1, {'class': 1}),
  ee.Feature(Canal2, {'class': 1}),
]);

//Define the image aduh anjir salah dimana sih
var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2");
var geometry = ee.FeatureCollection(polygons);
var image = imageCollection
.filterDate('2019-09-01', '2019-10-1')
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
                  .map(maskS2clouds)
                  //filter according to drawn boundary
.filterBounds(geometry);

             

// Get the values for all pixels in each polygon in the training.
var training = image.sampleRegions({
  // Get the sample from the polygons FeatureCollection.
  collection: polygons,
  // Keep this list of properties from the polygons.
  properties: ['class'],
  // Set the scale to get Landsat pixels in the polygons.
  scale: 30
});

// Create an SVM classifier with custom parameters.
var classifier = ee.Classifier.libsvm({
  kernelType: 'RBF',
  gamma: 0.5,
  cost: 10
});

// Train the classifier.
var trained = classifier.train(training, 'class', bands);

// Classify the image.
var classified = image.classify(trained);

// Display the classification result and the input image.
Map.setCenter(101.68287285738528,0.6988384299139916,16);
Map.addLayer(image, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 0.5, gamma: 2});
Map.addLayer(polygons, {}, 'training polygons');
Map.addLayer(classified,
             {min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['red', 'green']},
             'klasifikasi');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
var image = imageCollection
    .filterDate(...)
    .filter(...)
    .map(...)
    .filterBounds(...);

var training = image.sampleRegions(...);
```

Everything you have done to `imageCollection` still returns an image collection, not an image. In order to apply an image operation like `sampleRegions`, you need to decide what you want to do.

Do you want to take the *latest* pixel available in the filtered collection for each point? Then use `.mosaic()`:

```
var image = imageCollection
    .filterDate(...)
    .filter(...)
    .map(...)
    .filterBounds(...)
    .mosaic();
```

Do you want the median of the time series for each pixel? Then use `.median()` instead of `.mosaic()`. (Or `mean`, `min`, `max`, etc. are also available)

Do you want separate sampled points for *every image in the collection* at every region? Then map over it to sample each image:

```
var trainingImages = imageCollection
    .filterDate(...)
    .filter(...)
    .map(...)
    .filterBounds(...);

var trainingPoints = trainingImages.map(function (image) {
  return image.sampleRegions(...);
}).flatten();
```

(Note the `.flatten()` at the end; this is key because this produces a collection of points for each image in the collection of images, so it would be a collection of collections of points, and `.flatten()` turns it into a collection of points.)

Comment: Many thanks for the input, the .mosaic works perfectly with what i was aiming for!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to guess from your code, but with a little bit of debugging you might figure it out. Try to console.log what exactly `image.sampleRegions` is and what are the properties of `image` object. From there you might be able to see what's wrong - undefined property, wrong type, etc.

AD: After quick look into GEE docs I'd say try wrapping your collection porcessing into `ee.Image()`. Maybe that will help:

```js
var image = ee.Image(imageCollection
  .filterDate('2019-09-01', '2019-10-1')
  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
  .map(maskS2clouds)
  //filter according to drawn boundary
  .filterBounds(geometry));
```

Comment: thank you for the input, but somehow after I add 'ee.Image' the console keep stating that ee.image is not a function... maybe I skipped something else